# getting the number of clients connected

Tags: php, mongodb

How do I get the number of clients that are currently connected to my server running MongoDB using PHP?

or is it even possible because when the query is executed and when it ends the connection closes and so the connection is open only for a few moments?

Comment: you can check number of connections are server side instead using mongo> db.stats().connections or using mongostat command and check conn option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ...may help you

`db.serverStatus().connections`